# wordpress query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

я сделал поиск постов по указываемым параметрам таким образом

```
        if ( isset($location_search) && !empty($location_search) ) {
            $meta[] = array(
            'key' => 'post_location',
            'value' => $location_search );
        }

        $qargs = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        's'                 => $keyword,
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'orderby'           => 'author date',
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'cat'               => $catSearchID,
        'meta_query'        => array( 'relation' => 'AND', $meta )               
        );
```

с этим все в порядке, работает, выдает посты с указанным городом. все было ок, пока в опции поста post_location вписывался только один город. теперь заказчик попросил несколько городов для одного поста. я в этот же post_location через update_post_meta записываю массив из городов. но как в таком случае сделать поиск и проверку содержит ли post_location город который указали при поиске? как сюда вставить in_array() или что то в этом роде? не хватает мозгов :(

Comment: В каком виде хранятся записи? JSON/Разделитель?

Comment: по дефаулту в json, но могу что бы было через разделитель переписать лишь бы было проще решить проблему :)

Comment: Через разделитель, хоть LIKE сделать можно.

Comment: сделал через | как дальше? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть оператор compare. при его значении LIKE из данных выбираются указанное значение. добавил к своему коду. теперь все работает.
тут подробнее о compare https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70864/meta-query-compare-operator-explanation

```
            if ( isset($location_search) && !empty($location_search) ) {
                $meta[] = array(
                'key' => 'post_location',
                'value' => $location_search,
                'compare' => 'LIKE' );
            }

            $qargs = array(
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            's'                 => $keyword,
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'orderby'           => 'author date',
            'posts_per_page'    => 12,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'cat'               => $catSearchID,
            'meta_query'        => array( 'relation' => 'AND', $meta )               
            );
```

Comment: Ну вот, здорово. Оформите красиво ввиде ответа, что бы не минусовали, и выберите как верный. И вам плюс, и поможете кому то еще! Как оформите, дайте знать.

Comment: переписал ответ, но пометить как верный не могу. пишут что только через 2 дня смогу